# ios unwindsegue not showing correct drop-down options

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

This might be more of an xcode problem though I'm hoping someone might know someway to help.

I have a VC A that push's to VC B.

In VC A I have defined  `- (IBAction)doneUnWindingFromBToA :(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {}`

In VC C I defined   `- (IBAction)doneUnWindingFromBToC :(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {}`

When I drag a `UIButton` to the Exit button I only see doneUnWindingFromBToC - even though, that push `segue` has been deleted in the storyboard.

Currently, there is only one segue (push, from A to B) leading into B.

I have also tried to manually create a segue - dragging the scene's view controller icon to its exit icon.

How do I reset the dropdown?

UPDATE:

I commented out the code in VC C and now VC B doesnt let me ctrl drag into the Exit icon.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug. I'll file a report soon.

I solved it by creating another action method just like the first one (added one extra character) and now it works.